# Select query to find the unmatched records from selected values using in function in Oracle 10g

Tags: postgresql

I am using IN clause for column "job_no". In this in clause i checking 1000 values, query retreiving the values but some of the job number are not existed, then how to find unmattched values in the in clause.

Comment: Why do you write Oracle 10g in the subject, but tag the post with PostgreSQL. Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: From where are you getting the list of IDs and what do you intend to do with the unmatched IDs? If you edit your question to include the answer to those questions you are likely to get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you really are using Oracle:

```
create type table_of_integers is table of integer;
/

select * from table(table_of_integers(1, 2, 3))
where column_value not in (select job_no from my_table);
```

or you should be able to achieve the same thing using an `outer join`, such as this example for postgres:

```
select * 
from (select unnest(array[1, 2, 3]) as job_no) j 
     left outer join my_table using(job_no)
where my_table.job_no is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the values into a temporary table instead and do a LEFT OUTER JOIN to join with your data.

Comment: Not sure if Sundeep is using postgres or Oracle, but I don't think he is using SQL Server :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point: temporary tables are supported by both those platforms. For postgres, that can just be a "begin", "create temp table t(...) on commit drop", "copy t from stdin", *push data*, "select ....", "end" sequence. Which is still 6 turnarounds, but that's better than 1000, and scales up to more values being passed.

Comment: @araqnid just that on Oracle using an intermediate table (eg a GTT) for this sort of thing would be a last resort - whereas on SQL Server it is often the first resort. Postgres perhaps tries to have it both ways. Don't you agree?

Comment: @araqnid out of interest, what is a 'turnaround'?

Comment: Yeah, SQL Server guys love their table variables :) (almost as much as they love stored procedures) In postgres, temp table data isn't WAL-logged. Also in Postgres, all temp tables are local, not global. Unless there are lots of input values it isn't likely to escape the buffer cache, so it's not as inefficient as it perhaps looks. You could also do something like your answer, by using `values(1),(2),(3),....` as an inline view.

Comment: client/network/server turnaround- creating a temp table, populating and using it requires 6 server interactions (4 plus one each for begin/end transaction), whereas putting all the values into an inline view would be just one. Even if this isn't a significant factor, it is often perceived as one.

Comment: I think I'm assuming the OP has a string like '1, 2, 3' that he needs to insert into some dynamic SQL. I guess only Sundeep can tell us what he really wants...